# Separate Compilation and Linking of CUDA C++ Device Code with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

I want to add cuda code in existing C++ code base that uses cmake build systems. I found an article(link below) from NVIDIA that exactly shows how it can be done except it uses make build. I am new to cmake build system, but I gave good try by reading and experimenting stuff from other links on this website. So far no success! Does anybody has an idea about it ? If yes then please guide me.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/separate-compilation-linking-cuda-device-code/

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
message(STATUS "CMake version: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")

project(CUDAwithC)
find_package(CUDA 9.1 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(FindCUDA)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/cuda-9.1/include include)
set(SOURCE_FILES src/app.cpp src/particle.cpp src/v3.cpp)
cuda_add_executable(
    tee ${SOURCE_FILES}
)
set(
    CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS
    ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};
    -x cu -gencode -arch=compute_20 -dc
)

target_link_libraries(
    tee /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so
)
```

Comment: cuda 9.1 doesn't support `-arch=compute_20`.  [This](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/prop_tgt/CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION.html) may be of interest.   Use that instead of the `-dc` flag.  If you do a bit of searching on the `cuda` tag here on SO you'll find other questions about separate compilation that probably have what you want.  Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcuda%5D+and+%5Bcmake%5D+CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION)

Comment: @RobertCrovella, the post from Nvidia adds the cuda code into the cpp files but other posts on stackoverflow focused on working with both .cu files and .cpp files. I couldn't find any answer that refer to the method mentioned in the link.

Comment: You couldn't find any answer that refers to `CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION` property?  I gave you a search link that returns several examples.

Comment: Hi @RobertCrovella thank you very much for your suggestions. I am able to build the code with cmake. Solution that worked: Convert all the .cpp file to .cu file and set the cuda_seperable_complaition on. However, I still don't get the whole idea. All the files have some CUDA specific keywords and extension .cu so, these files must be compiled by nvcc withot setting cuda_seperable_complaition on then why does it only works when seperable_compliation is on?. If I don't enable it then it get linking error for the function which does not have any cuda specific keyword. Would you please explain?

Comment: separable compilation is described in the [nvcc manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).  It is needed any time you have device code in one compilation unit that calls device code in another compilation unit.  If you have such a scenario in your project, then simply converting everything to .cu files and compiling with nvcc is not enough.  You must also enable separable compilation.  Beyond that I can't explain anything specific to your project, as you've not given any sort of a complete example to work with.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for sharing your knowledge with me. I got the idea now when to use separate compilation. I used the source code from  nvidia link(mentioned above) as an example to understand the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see the error messages.

From just looking at your code, instead of specifying the library path, use ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}.

Dump the flags section and use the OPTIONS argument for cuda_add_executable to pass the -arch flag.

Don't use include_directories (best practices), use target_include_directories instead and pass it ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}. You shouldn't have to do that at all as cuda_add_executable does that for you (reportedly).

It's helpful to enable compile_commands.json to see what the build system is trying to do.

```
set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON )
```

Also worth reading through FindCUDA.cmake to see what it offers.

```
/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake
```